# Which way should I solder these XLR terminals?

Tags: connector, charger, power-connector, xlr, ev-charger

I need to install a female XLR connector on my electric bike to work with a new charger which has an XLR plug. Before soldering the wires, I wanted to check that I'm making the connection in the correct way. Normally, an XLR plug has its positive terminal on terminal 2 and ground on terminal 1. However, on the charger, it looks like terminal 1 is the positive terminal and terminal 2 is the ground. I need to know which way I should solder my wires here.

[image: Male connector]

[image: Female connector]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no standard. Do as the charger does.

Comment: An observation: both solder joints (#2 especially) look cold to me.  Those cup terminals are notorious in my experience for trapping air behind a plug of solder.  Since this is a power application, I would reflow them with extra flux.

Comment: Make sure you check red is actually positive. Sometimes you get surprises.

Comment: Please post the manufacturer name of your electric bike. This way everyone will know to avoid them due to the choice of using an audio/data connector for power.

Comment: Actually, the original connector on the bike was a Chogori 23002515-03, and it was obviously impossible to find a matching charger. The only 72V chargers I could find online came either with an XLR plug or some sort of modified IEC 320 C15. I'm aware that XLR are not meant to carry this amount of current/voltage. I'll redo the soldering joints.

Answer (score 3):

Do not look at how audio devices connect the wires.

Connect it exactly as the charger is wired.

That said, it's extremely bad idea to use 3-pin XLR as charger connector, as it is usually used for many other incompatible purposes, such as analog audio and digital data transmission. Make sure the connector you bought is rated for the voltage and current you require.